# F1001 Internal code generator error in RAD STUDIO 2009

Tags: compiler-errors, c++builder, c++builder-2009

I'm getting this worthless error in my code.  it's very consistant and restarting the compiler hasn't done anything.  Has anyone else ever solved this?

```
while( int CharPos = _Message.Pos(_What) )
{
    _Message.Insert( _With, CharPos);
    _Message.Delete(CharPos + 1, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... apparently the compiler breaks when you try to declare an int in the while loop's condition.

Answer (score 2):

You could:

- follow [QC#66963](http://qc.codegear.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=66963)
- search for F1001 on qc.codegear.com: http://dn.codegear.com/search?qall=f1001&sourcelang=cpp&allsites=y
- do what the compiler documentation has to say about F1001, i.e. contact technical support.
- all of the above :)

Edit: By the way, have you tried compiling the offending source file (or at least a minimal skeleton file containing just a main() and the offending code) with the command line compiler? BCB tends to hide a lot of detailed error info when compiling from the IDE - using the command line compiler tends to show the real error. Not foolproof, but worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected to be addressed in the soon to be released Update 3 for RAD Studio 2009.